# How add extra menu on top?

Tags: wordpress, menu, polylang

I created menu (in photo "2")
how to create additional sticky menu (in photo 1) with language swithcer and telephone/email? [image]

Comment: Edit the file (most likely header.php) and add that tab menu there?

Comment: Tab menu? what is it?

Comment: ok forget about tab menu, i mean just the menu u wanted. code it in.